# Finding Flights to One of Many Cities

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, open-jaw

Currently planning a trip to see multiple cities in relatively close proximity. I expect to be travelling by land between them, so it does not matter so much which city I travel to and back from. It could be the same or a different one. The main concern is to find a good price.

What can I use to search for flights from a specific departure location to a set of cities simultaneously? I have been trying out combinations of cities, including various open jaw permutations, and dates and it is getting tedious.

Comment: So a one-way flight from A or B or C or D or E to F or G or H or I or J for example?

Comment: Did you try the [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/)? Personally that's my go-to for multi-city open-jaws

Comment: I think the OP means, flights from A to (B or C or D) then (B or C or D) back to A

Comment: Yeah, you can do that on some sites, but we'll wait for him to clarify I guess.

Comment: Right. Yes from A to (B, C or D) and back from (B, C or D) to A.

Comment: @Gagravarr - How can I put multiple options one entry of the ITA Matrix? That's what I'm after, one among *n* destinations with a fixed departure and return airport (home).

Comment: @Itai Just put commas between the airport codes, eg "from = LHR", "to = JFK, LGA, EWR, IAD"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this on [Kayak](http://kayak.com).  Select a round-trip flight, and in the second box (destination), you can enter multiple airport codes separated by commas, up to 4.  (You can also enter multiple airport codes in the origin box.)

For example, entering "DEN" and "ORD,IND,DTW,CLE" gave me [this list of results](https://www.kayak.com/flights/DEN-ORD,IND,DTW,CLE/2015-07-11/2015-07-22) for flights from Denver to any of Chicago, Indianapolis, Detroit or Cleveland, and returning to Denver.  By default it includes multi-airport itineraries (e.g. DEN-ORD paired with IND-DEN) but there is a checkbox in the results page for "Depart/Return same" which will exclude those itineraries, and only show you trips where you return from the same airport where you arrived (e.g. DEN-ORD can only be paired with ORD-DEN).  There are also checkboxes where you can turn some of your airports on or off.

Comment: bah, beat me to it :)

Comment: Great! I'll try this tonight. Used Kayak for a while but I didn't know this could be done.

Comment: Skyscanner does something like that, you can either set an airport and other airports near or you can select a country (useful if it is a smallish country you want to visit.) There might be more options. www.skyscanner.net, will adjust to your location.

Answer (score 4):

The [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com) will let you search for this. (It doesn't let you book, but does tell you enough to let a travel agent recreate and book them for you, see [this question for details](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/travel-agents-can-they-match-ita-travel-matrix-prices)). Simply pop in several airport codes in the from and/or to boxes separated by commas, such as shown:

[image]

Then on the search results see what was the cheapest combination. In this case, Brussels is our cheapest departure point, and combinations with different airports used are shown in red to highlight the change:

[image]

The details tab will let you get all the info you need to go off elsewhere and make the booking for the flight you prefer

Comment: Another great answer. I've been trying this in every flight search engine and some of them get really really confused! At least those in these answers support it.